# What causes icon corruption in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons, file-corruption

I have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/38426/what-causes-desktop-shortcut-icons-to-randomly-change) and this workaround does not work for me.

[image: Start Menu]

Now when I launch FileZilla the icon shows fine on the taskbar.

1. How can I fix this in Windows 7?
2. What causes icon corruption?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know what causes icon corruption.

To rebuild the icon cache:

- Enable **Show hidden files and folders**.
- Open **My Computer**
- Navigate to `%systemdrive%\Users\"your User Name"\AppData\Local`
- Look for **IconCache.db** and delete it permanently (holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd>)
- Reboot the system.

Comment: You don't havce to reboot.  Just open task manager, stop explorer.exe and then 'File'=>'Run'=>"explorer" to start a new instance.  If you don't have a taskbar, then ctrl+shift+esc will open task manager

Comment: Both your answer and Andrew Backer's comment helped a lot. How come I can surf the official support sites of vendors for hours without result, but go to superuser and have my issues resolved in minutes? Nice work!

Comment: I have this problem with pinned programs that reside on a network drive that's manually mapped after starting Windows. Deleting IconCache.db alone didn't work. This command recreated the icons: `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`

Comment: @DanDascalescu: Interesting tip. More info to be found in [A Quicker Way to Refresh the Icon Cache in Windows 7](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/refresh-icon-cache-windows-7-quickly/).

Comment: By the way there's quicker way of getting to `%systemdrive%\Users\"your User Name"\AppData\Local`, it's `%LocalAppData%`.

Answer (score 4):

Reasons of Corruption are Obscure until now..
You may have to Rebuild the Icon Cache in Windows 7

**Information**

> If one or more of your icons are not
>   displaying correctly, or that your
>   icon cache is corrupted, then you
>   might consider rebuilding the icon
>   cache to reset and reload the icon
>   images into the icon cache.

**Note**
This will not help with any of the following icon issues:

> 1-A shortcut's icon that is not displayed properly due to the source
>   of the shortcut being moved or deleted. You may need to recreate a
>   new shortcut directly from the source
>   (ex: program's exe) file to replace it
>   instead.
>      2- All icons for a specific file extension display the wrong icon. This
>   may be do to setting the wrong
>   association for what program to open
>   the file extension instead.   You can
>   restore the default file extension's
>   associations to fix this icon instead.

If you have check that the source icon is not corrupted use this solution:
**[Windows 7 - Icon Cache - Rebuild](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html)** *from the SevenForum tutorials*

Comment: If deleting `IconCache.db` doesn't work, try running `ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache`. The latter worked when Windows lost the icons of pinned programs that reside on a network drive that's manually mapped after starting Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this topic is so old... But i had this problem just now.

And, **the problem is not the icon cache**. *The problem is the "arrow" for the shortcuts*.

If you see closely, you can see the icon, but not the "icon arrow for shortcut" that is the problem.

Maybe you changed (like me) the icon for shortcuts (or maybe not), but you can fix the problem resetting or changing again the arrow for shortcuts.

Using [Windows Shortcut Arrow Editor](https://winaero.com/windows-shortcut-arrow-editor/)