# Google Chrome icon not visible

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, icons

For some reason after I've installed Google Chrome the Google Chrome icons were not visible. I even reinstalled it and the same happens.

[image: Google Chrome icon does not show on Taskbar]
[image: Not shown in start menu either]

How can I fix this problem?
I also posted on Chromium issues back in July but got no reply.

Comment: try cleaning your registry.

Comment: Can you give a more detail answer on how exactly I should "clean" it please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix broken taskbar icons in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/173442/how-to-fix-broken-taskbar-icons-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing Google Chrome icon is a [common issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118167), but I couldn't find any clear solutions for this problem. I found several methods that have worked for some people, and so I suggest you to try them. Even though I can't guarantee it will work, it's worth giving a shot:

- Open Microsoft Internet Explorer, make it your default browser, then go to Google Chrome and make it your default browser.
- Unpin Google Chrome from Start Menu, change its icon in Properties, and pin it back.
- Type in the Start Menu search bar "chrome" and look for chromesetup.exe. Click on it.

Comment: Do you mean Internet Explorer and not Windows Explorer in your first bullet point?
But the second suggestion worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

Unpin the item from your taskbar and check the shortcut in the 'Google Chrome' folder in start menu. If you have the same issue as me, the start menu icon will also be broken.

To fix this, right click the shortcut and selected properties. Then click 'Change Icon...' and select the chrome icon. Click 'OK' and then 'OK' again. Provide administrator details if asked.

Then simply right click on the fixed shortcut and select 'Pin to Taskbar'.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run Task Manager

   - end explorer.exe
   - run new task: cmd.exe
2. type

   ```
   cd %userprofile%\appdata\local
   ```
3. type

   ```
   del iconcache.db /a
   ```
4. type

   ```
   exit
   ```
5. Back in Task Manager

   - run new task: explorer.exe

Comment: Didn't work for me.  But ironically, it's only the small icon that's missing.  The medium size still works. (Win 10 btw)

Comment: This thing worked. btw what does `/a` do in `del`?