# Pinning task bar icon shows old icon image

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

I have desktop application that changes the default icon after login. I am using Windows 7 ultimate.

After login, if I pin the task bar icon, the icon is not updated and shows the default icon. When I unpin the task bar icon it shows the correct updated icon.

I did rebuild the icon cache, but it didn't work. Is there a way to get the right icons when I pin it to task-bar?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: I don't enough reputation to post images.

Comment: It is similar to this issue: http://superuser.com/questions/173442/how-to-fix-broken-taskbar-icons-in-windows-7

Comment: What does "changes the default icon after login" mean?

Comment: I am changing the icon at run-time after login

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're not changing the icon of the actual executable, but rather some shortcut.  Even if it SEEMS like the executable; not all shortcuts have the little peel icon.  Run program, from Task Manager, see what's the actual executable and change that.  If it doesn't update, restart 'Windows Explorer' from Task Manager.

For further help, we'd need to know the program in question and your method of changing the icon.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This a an old question, However, if anyone would need it.

To get the icon the taskbar same as the one you set to the form.
1. Go to your project properties
2. Choose 'Application'
3. At Resources, choose 'Icon and manifest'
4. Set your chosen icon.